# How to permanently chmod 777 for PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, centos

Before you start killing me about how I should not chmod 777, this is rather different than what's in many other topics.

The situation now is that I have this directory NOT accessible from the web (`/var/lib/folder/`) but I want PHP to be able to access it so that it can read, write and execute from the directory.

A simple solution would be to chmod (as root), 777 the folder, but here comes the problem.
Another user, say John, writes to this directory. As anyone would know, files that John write entitles him to be the owner, and as such PHP is not the owner. Somehow, files that John write always become 755 instead of 777 (and as a result PHP cannot access).

Is there any way to either:

1. Make John always write to that directory in 777
   or
2. Make the directory such that all files that John write become fully accessible to PHP.

Comment: Your problem will always be encountered. 777, read write, execute.. Global permissions for that directory, anything/anyone can perform actions within that directory... If the directory is specific for a user, then why not look into `chown`

Comment: I mean the directory is 777, but files within that directory aren't. So when John writes to the directory, PHP can't write over the files John wrote, but I want php to do so.
chmod -R is only a one-time solution. subsequent files are still 755 (php unreadable)

Comment: Set an ACL on the directory: `setfacl -d -m u:php:rwx /var/lib/folder/`. This gives user `php` rwx rights for new files. You don't need chmod 777.

Comment: @roland OMG that worked! ><
could you post it below so that I can accept answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need chmod.

Set an ACL on the directory:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:php:rwx /var/lib/folder/
```

This gives user php rwx rights for new files (-d = default).

You can change the ACL for existing files in the folder with:

```
setfacl -R -m u:php:rwx /var/lib/folder/
```